# An error in a simple program: TypeError: into object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, function, pygame

I've been trying to program a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game for about 1 week now >.<'

Full source: http://pastebin.com/6dgjen9u

When testing my program in `main()`:

**I'm getting the error:**

```
File "x:\programming\python\tac.py", line 64, in display_board
    print "\n\t", board[0], "  |", board[1], " |", board[2]
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

**The responsible functions here:**

```
def display_board(board):
    """ Display game board on screen."""
    print "\n\t", board[0], "  |", board[1], " |", board[2]
    print "\t", "------------"
    print "\t", board[3], "  |", board[4], " |", board[5]
    print "\t", "------------"
    print "\t", board[6], "  |", board[7], " |", board[8], "\n"

def cpu_move(board, computer, human):
    """ Takes computer's move + places on board."""

    # make a copy of the board
    board = board[:]
    bestmoves = (0,2,6,8,4,3,5,1,7)

    # if computer can win, play that square:
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winning_board(board) == computer:
            print "[debug] cpu win:", move
            return move
        # undo the move because it was empty before
        board[move] = EMPTY

    # if player can win, block that square:
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winning_board(board) == human:
            print "[debug] block human:", move
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY

        # chose first best move that is legal
    for move in bestmoves:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            board[move] = computer
            print "[debug] next best move:", move
            return move


def change_turn(turn):
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X

def main():
    human, computer = go_first()
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    turn = X
    while winning_board(board) == None:
        if human == turn:
            board = human_move(board, human)
            turn = change_turn(turn)
            display_board(board)
        else:
            board = cpu_move(board, computer, human)
            turn = change_turn(turn)
            display_board(board)
```

I have no idea what is causing the error because `display_board(board)` works fine for the human's move. It just fails when the computer takes its move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cpu_move` returns an integer here:

```
return move
```

Change it to return a list.

Comment: That's right. I got confused about return values. I should've done `return board`

Comment: @user2071506 yes, the traceback you didn't post may already told you which line introduces that error

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the `human_move` function, but anyways, your problem is that you're trying to index an integer.

When you return `board`, from `cpu_move` you are returning an int. Look at what you're returning: you're returning `move`, which is an integer, and doesn't have a `__getitem__` method (which is the method that indexing calls).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your `cpu_move` function return an `int` here:

```
for move in bestmoves:
    if move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        print "[debug] next best move:", move
        return move
```

This may be the problem as you are using this value for the  `display_board` function:

```
board = cpu_move(board, computer, human)
turn = change_turn(turn)
display_board(board)
```